# I need to reference a cell value for slide Array VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have this VBA in PowerPoint which works perfectly as it is.

```vb
Sub hideme()
    Dim x As Integer
    On Error GoTo errhandler

    For x = 1 To 6
        ActivePresentation.slides(x).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTrue
    Next x

    Exit Sub
errhandler:

End Sub
```

Can one of the fine experts on here advise, or, correct this so the 1 to 6 can be a cell reference (I13) from an external excel file (filename.xlsm)?

Comment: So the cell I13 contains "1 to 6"?

Comment: No, cell I13 has a series of numbers that i want to correspond to slide numbers (eg) 2,5,9,16,56,88.......... would select slides 2,5,9,16,56,88